# Power/Battery Management System Prototype: Custom PCB or Evaluation Modules from TI?

Tags: power, batteries, power-electronics

I am developing a battery/power management system for a medical device that runs off of 12VDC. I notice that TI offers a lot of evaluation modules in power management, and wonder if I should start from there, or if I should look at individual electronic component and try to piece up a prototype PCB.

**Any input would be appreciated!!!**

Comment: Buy a handful of different evaluation modules.  If you go the make your own PCB route you have to guess which chip will work for your application. With evaluation modules, you can conduct trials on battery life, usage requirements, emi , leakage currents  etc. and narrow down on a suitable chipset, and you can solder different parts onto the evaluation module to see what mods your design would need.

Comment: @BobT That really clears things up! Thank you, and I will go check out different evaluation modules from TI. All the best!